# How can I use an HP LaserJet M1536dn printer as a fax machine (outgoing) on Windows Server 2008

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-server-2008-r2, hp, drivers, fax

I'm running Windows Server 2008R2 and I'm trying to set up an HP M1526dn as a fax machine (this is a multi-function device). The printer is not directly connected to the server, but is on the network, and works fine as a fax for other Windows 7 machines as well as Macs that are on the network.

When I attempt to add it to Windows Server 2008R2, it gets added as a printer only. I am unable to use it as a fax. I'm only looking to use it for outgoing faxes.

Any ideas on how to get this to work? When I called HP's tech support line, as soon as I told them it was Server 2008, they told me to call Microsoft.

I even went so far as to set up a Windows 7 machine, added the HP to it as a fax (which works as expected), and then tried to share it with the Server 2008 machine. No joy. It again works fine as a printer, but refuses to work as a fax.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is getting the correct drivers. Typically you will need the 'Full Feature' driver to use the fax functionality, often they will not release a server version of this but rather a Universal PCL5/6 driver. Even when you manage to get the full driver to install, the server will not be able to serve the fax to users any more than a PC can.

This is what is normally done:
If you are hoping to use the Fax and Scan role to allow users to receive and send faxes through the build in Windows fax on their machines you will often need a dedicated fax modem that can be directly controlled by the server, often in the form of a USB or PCI fax modem.

Comment: I don't quite understand your comment "Even when you manage to get the full driver to install, the server will not be able to serve the fax to users any more than a PC can." This printer works perfectly well as a fax for Windows 7 and for Mac OS X based machines. It's only the Server that has a problem.

Comment: There is a function built into Windows Server that allows it to become a fax server, storing, managing and sending faxes, with templates and various other features. In my experience you cannot use a standalone Fax/MFP as a modem for that service.

Comment: I tried that too. I used a Zoom USB fax modem, which I have used successfully before, but no matter what I tried, when I attempted to send a fax, I got a generic error message "The fax can't be sent because of an unexpected error." in the Windows Fax and Scan application. I can't seem to find any more details on what this unexpected error is.